# How to get sharedposts field with FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm working with an application that collects a list of users that have either liked or commented on a post in a Facebook fan page.  I would like to modify this application to also collect the list of users that have shared a post they saw on a fan page.   From what I've read elsewhere, it's supposed to be either impossible to do this or only somewhat possible through difficult workarounds that don't use Facebook's API.

I have not found any mention of the "sharedposts" field, which I found myself while playing with the Graph API Explorer.  I don't even see this listed in Facebook's own documentation for the Graph API.  But it exists and appears to give the data about shares of a Status (it is not available for Posts).  For example, this link to the Graph API Explorer should bring up a list of Shares of a particular status update on the Walmart fan page:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10151617223914236%3Ffields%3Dsharedposts

My question for anyone else who has used this field:  can I get this field through FQL?  I tried a few queries, but couldn't come up with one that worked.  I don't see it documented for FQL, but then again it's not documented for Graph API and it still exists there.

I want to use FQL because I'm using the Facebook SDK for .Net (http://facebooksdk.net/) which has a method called "ExecuteFQL" that I'm using to send FQL queries to Facebook.

Alternatively, if FQL can't return that field, is there a method I could use to query the Graph API in a different way using the Facebook SDK for .Net?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious that I'm very new to Facebook development.  I didn't realize how easy it was to query the Graph API.  I figured out I can get the shared posts directly with a URL like so:  https://graph.facebook.com/10151617223914236?fields=sharedposts&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN.  So I'll use that in lieu of an FQL query.